# Add an `aws_acm_certificate` resource to a terraform file causes terraform to ignore vars

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Using the `aws_acm_certificate` resources makes terraform ignore provided variables.

Here's a simple terraform file:

```
variable "aws_access_key_id" {}
variable "aws_secret_key" {}
variable "region" { default = "us-west-1" }

provider "aws" {
  alias = "prod"

  region = "${var.region}"
  access_key = "${var.aws_access_key_id}"
  secret_key = "${var.aws_secret_key}"
}

resource "aws_acm_certificate" "cert" {
  domain_name       = "foo.example.com"
  validation_method = "DNS"

  tags {
    project = "foo"
  }

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }

}
```

Running `validate`, `plan`, or `apply` fails:

```
$ terraform validate -var-file=my.tfvars 
$ cat my.tfvars
region = "us-west-2"
aws_secret_key = "secret"
aws_access_key_id = "not as secret"
```

Comment: I have a much simpler case now. I think this might be a bug.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong in your codes.

Please do some cleans and run again **(only run the rm command when you fully understand what you are doing)**

```
rm -rf .terraform
rm terraform.tfstate*

terraform fmt
terraform get -update=true
terraform init
terraform plan
```

Comment: run `terraform fmt` to format the codes, maybe some hide characters make the trouble.